External monitor not working with Ubuntu
Laptop hp Pavilion dm4
Dual boot windows 10
Laptop screen is broken
VGA connection
Not sure about Ubuntu version
Can't see anything but the Ubuntu logo with the jelly fish
Please help

Use lsb_release -a to find the os version

Thanks.  Tha laptop screen is broken, that is why I'm using external monitor. Window 10 is visible on the monitor
